# How do you get Java Spring Boot to run on an M1 mac when it requires libzstd-jni.dylib?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apple-m1

On my **Apple M1** laptop I'm trying to run spring boot, but I get the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no zstd-jni in java.library.path: /Users/me/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Unsupported OS/arch, cannot find /darwin/aarch64/libzstd-jni.dylib or load zstd-jni from system libraries. Please try building from source the jar or providing libzstd-jni in your system.
```

Being on a mac I don't have `/darwin/aarch64/` folder and I can't find where to install or download `libzstd-jni.dylib`.

I installed Java through the Arm 64 DMG Installer

```
$ java -version 

- java version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18 LTS
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86)
- Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-LTS-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

There is a `libjli.dylib` file in the **MasOS** folder in JDK:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib`

I added `libjli.dylib` to `/Library/Java/Extensions/`, but that didn't help.

I'm out of options. If anyone can help me I would be super appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official repository: https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni

[In binary releases](https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni#binary-releases_) I see support for aarch64. I would try to bump to the latest version:

```
implementation 'com.github.luben:zstd-jni:1.5.2-1'
```

(I don't have this kind of problem, it's just a guess -- let me know if it helps.)